# What is a monster pet or allied creature referring to DMG p 296?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dungeon

The DMG in it's Dungeon chamber contents table on p 296 reference a "Monster (pet or allied creature). Does this mean this Monster is allied to the dominant inhabitant, or is this supposed to be a monster the characters can talk themselves past? Or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 11):

The paragraph directly above the table explains how to interpret the table.

> In the Dungeon Chamber Contents table, a "dominant inhabitant" is a creature that controls an area. Pets and allied creatures are subservient to the dominant inhabitant.

So yes, this entry in the table refers to an ally of the dominant inhabitant. Note that this does not preclude the characters talking themselves past it, or finding another solution. They are free to deal with the creature in whatever way they can.